# php include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear' error in cpanel

Tags: php, html, include, cpanel

I was testing my php application on My wampServer (localhost) and its ALL works!
But, when i uploaded this same application to my webserver i got this inssue:

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'util/DB_Connect.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/th27664/minierp.sistemaids.com.br/header.php on line 5

I have no idea why, because its the same files that i used to my localhost application

Here is part of my code:

```
<body class="animsition">
<?php 

        require_once 'header.php';
    require 'controller/controllerProduto.php';
        require 'controller/ControllerEmitente.php';
        $controle = new ControllerProduto();
        $ControleEmitente = new ControllerEmitente();
```

Important Detail: My header.php file is on the same folder of this file.

Thank you, very much!

Comment: It looks to me like the error is in the header.php, looking for until/DB_Connect.php, it’s not an issue trying to load header.php like your question seems to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use either `root relative url` like,

> require_once '/home/youraccount/public_htm/yourdirectory/header.php'

or `absolute url` like

> require_once 'http://yoursite.com/yourdirectory/header.php'

Don't use `document relative url`.

Comment: I tryed to do this, but it does not work. Is there some configuration at apache?

Comment: When you define root relative url, please try to define the path  from the bottom most  directory. I just gave you the examples. It may also cause trouble if your remote directory is password protected. You can try after removing your directory password. Otherwise you should inform it to your host.

Comment: @KlantoAguntuk I have a custom script for shipping estimation -> https://pastebin.com/em9kgk5M , the script working if it is available on root_folder/sp_cost.php. if i  moved to my project folder like root_folder/my_project/sp_cost.php  t=return error, error line 3, how to solve the require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php'); issue>

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is in the `.htaccess` file. If you use html extension files and write inside on php, in `.htaccess` you should add:
`AddType application / x-httpd-php5 .html`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the system default config (yaml below) for php-fpm in cPanel to set the php `open_basedir` as a security measure. Since doing that, I also got the `include_path` error you had.

To fix, add this:

```
php_value_include_path: 
  name: php_value[include_path]
  value: "[% documentroot %]"
```

**Mind the indentation.**

To:

```
/var/cpanel/ApachePHPFPM/system_pool_defaults.yaml
```

Then, for good measure, I force WHM to rehandle the file by using the WHM steps:

1. Home »Software »MultiPHP Manager (System PHP-FPM Configuration Tab)
2. Change Max Requests by 1 (up or down) then scroll down and hit Save Configuration
3. Home »Restart Services »PHP-FPM service for Apache (restart the service)

Hope that helps!